# mvc. how to solve an issue with multiple models

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I need to create an partial view of loging form, which will be always on top of any page(like Facebook's) . This form is using logon model which I created. The main content of my page uses other models. For example news model or contact model. Is there any option of implementing multi model view? Or shall I rewrite my loging to use only jquery? Mvc's textboxfor and validation is very usefull for me and I don't want to replace it to pure jquery.

Answer (score 0):

Create a partial view for your login form and add it to your main layout page. You can call an overloaded method as such:

`@Html.Partial("_LoginPartial", new LoginModel())`

This will allow your partial view to have a different model.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your Logic model as base model and derive other models from this base model. This way, your View will be bound with both the models. i.e. when you'll call your login partial view and send it the model

```
@Html.RenderPartial("login", Model)
```

it will automatically bind with the login model.